# How to implement the OBS functionality in HTML format?

Tags: javascript, obs

I need to deploy scenes and their sources right in one web project so i can use it's flow in OBS without building scenes in the OBS itself.

Are there any libraries or ready solutions for this? Maybe exist some programs which allow to create scenes in it's editor and then access their flow with url?

Comment: If you can setup your own HTML5 web project using a commercial or online tool, you can then host it on a server.  Then use the "Browser" as a source and point it at your live web-page.  If that isn't your question, please be more specific.

Comment: @mazecreator about this *commercial or online tool* was the question. Anyway that's some late, thx